# Gitlab CI breaking on unit tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gitlab, jestjs, gitlab-ci

Two of my tests are passing locally but not on GitlabCI, and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

I have read [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/4880) that macOS is not case sensitive, and the ci might be, so I double checked all the spelling and everything came looks just fine.

Here's the filesystem layout:

```
  src/
    App.jsx
    App.test.jsx
    components/
      A/
        index.js 
        B/
          C/
            CContainer.jsx 
            CContainer.test.jsx
```

Below is the error code:

```
FAIL  src/components/A/B/C/CContainer.test.jsx


● Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module './CContainer' from 'CContainer.test.jsx'

  at Resolver.resolveModule (../../../tmp/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:179:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/A/B/C/CContainer.test.jsx:3:29)
```

My code from `CContainer.test.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { CContainer } from './CContainer';

const props = {
  saveTempUser: () => '',
  history: {},
  user: {},
};

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  shallow(<CContainer {...props} />);
});
```

The two files are siblings, and `CContainer` is simply:

```
...
export class CContainer extends Component {
...
}
...
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CContainer)
```

What's weird is in the top level `App.test.js` the same file causes a problem:

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js


● Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module './B/C/CContainer' from 'index.js'

  at Resolver.resolveModule (../../../tmp/node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:179:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/A/index.js:4:29)
```

And `index.js` is just:

```
import ConnectedCContainer, { CContainer} from './B/C/CContainer'
...


export {
  ...
  ConnectedCContainer,
  CContainer
}.
```

Any ideas? I'm currently configuring a local runner to try and debug and will come back with more info when I have some.

Comment: The problem is usually occurred when you haven't set the moduleFileExtension for jest. But It should fail on local also. However, can you double check your `jest configuration` in package.json and post it here. Do you use the same command in local and in gitlab CI for testing, anw?

Comment: Hey Dat. There's nothing in `package.json` right now, it's defaulted to whatever comes out of `create-react-app`. It looks like .jsx is the default: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulefileextensions-array-string

Comment: That's weird. I can't find exactly what's the problem here. But how about just using `.js` instead of `.jsx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the case of the file that was different than what was in git. Removing the file from git and adding a new file with the desired case fixed the problem.